# CXF Client Side Duplication of targetnamespace

Tags: java, cxf, web-services

I am hosting a webservice and a webapp on the same server, generated from wsdl2java.  I can contact the service just fine through SoapUI and it returns a single namespace declaration when posted to the live server, but when I am working locally and use SoapUI it generates two instances of xlmns="" instead of a single one in my xml.  I have copied below an example xml file:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<SendResponse xmlns="http://myendpoint.org/service" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<Receipt>
<MyReceipt xmlns:ns3="http://myendpoint.org/service" xmlns="" xmlns="" xmlns:ns6="http://myapp.myserver.net/myservicegroup/myservice/V01" receiptVersion="V01">
  <ReceiptHeader>
    <ReceiptTimestamp>2010-04-13T08:27:03.036-04:00</ReceiptTimestamp>
  </ReceiptHeader>
  <TransmissionReceipt>
    <TransmissionID>testuser</TransmissionID>
    <TransmissionTimestamp>2010-04-13T08:27:03.036-04:00</TransmissionTimestamp>
  </TransmissionReceipt>
</MyReceipt></Receipt></SendResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

So when it unmarshalls, it fails badly when I use my webapp as a webservice client.  Why is CXF adding a second namespace? I watched the debug all the way through until the return and it looked 100% perfect on the webservice side, no duplicate name space at all.  It does not happen until the return of the xml to the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML, attributes are unique to each element, so if this occurs then it is probably a bug and you should report it as such.  I've worked with CXF before and it's a great library, but it's unfortunately not perfect. I had to mess around with various versions, upgrading to an unstable one to get around the bugs I encountered.

[W3C XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Attribute)

> An attribute name MUST NOT appear more than once in the same start-tag or empty-element tag.